# gulp.js allowEmpty:true does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, thymeleaf

In my gulp.js code, I use the replace method to replace the html tags `src` and `href` attributes:

```
// HTML
function html(callback) {
    return src([paths.src.html, '!./src/partials/**/*'])
        .pipe(fileinclude({
            prefix: '@@',
            basepath: '@file'
        }))
        .pipe(replace(/[^(th:src)]src="(.{0,10})node_modules/g, 'src="$1assets/libs'))
        .pipe(replace(/[^(th:href)]href="(.{0,10})node_modules/g, 'href="$1assets/libs'))
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(replace(/[^(th:href)]href=".\//g, 'href="'))
        .pipe(replace(/[^(th:href)]href="(.{0,14})assets/g, 'href="../$1static/assets'))
        .pipe(replace(/[^(th:src)]src=".\//g, 'src="'))
        .pipe(replace(/[^(th:src)]src="(.{0,14})assets/g, 'src="../$1static/assets'))

    .pipe(cached())

    .pipe(dest(paths.dist.html))
        .pipe(browsersync.stream());
    callback();
}
```

My HTML file is as follows:

```
<!-- Libs JS -->
<script th:src="@{/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js}" src="@@webRoot/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js}" src="@@webRoot/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/assets/libs/simplebar/dist/simplebar.min.js}" src="@@webRoot/node_modules/simplebar/dist/simplebar.min.js"></script>


<!-- Theme JS -->
<!-- build:js @@webRoot/assets/js/theme.min.js -->
<script th:src="@{/assets/js/main.js}" src="@@webRoot/assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/assets/js/darkMode.js}" src="@@webRoot/assets/js/darkMode.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

As you can see above, the 'th:src' and 'th:href' attributes should not be used to include anything (because they are Thymeleaf attributes with nothing to do with frontend), but (I assume) because they contain'src' and 'href' substrings/keywords, it considers including values of'src' and 'href' attributes.

To summarize, gulp.js should evaluate just the values of the'src' and 'href' properties to include, but not 'th:src' and 'th:href'.

This is the error I get:

```
[22:04:16] 'html' errored after 139 ms
[22:04:16] Error: Error: File not found with singular glob: C:\project_folder\src\@{/assets/css/theme.css} (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (C:\project_folder\node_modules\gulp-useref\index.js:63:32)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Pumpify.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Pumpify.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Pumpify.Duplexify._destroy (C:\project_folder\node_modules\duplexify\index.js:191:15)
    at C:\project_folder\node_modules\duplexify\index.js:182:10
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
[22:04:16] 'build' errored after 158 ms
```

I attempted to solve the problem by using 'allowEmpty:true':

```
src([paths.src.html, '!./src/partials/**/*'],{allowEmpty:true})...
```

It didn't work, and I received the same error.

If I've missed something about the problem and you cannot understand it, please let me know so I can include it here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're wondering why the posted answer was deleted, I replied to your comment about inhuman reaction speeds saying that I believe the answer may have come from ChatGPT, and within a second of me posting that the author deleted their answer.

Comment: Actually, that post was too close to be an accepted answer.